# Blue Prism - text box login and password entered but website says please enter user name and password

Tags: authentication, blueprism

I am just started learning BP - I have spied the the login text box like user name and password;
when I run the application it enters the user name and password that I have specified in the data items correctly and then click on LOGIN button; but website throws that 
-please enter username
- please enter password
So, I feel that website didnt really recognize the text that BP entered in both fields thus it thrwos the error; any idea what else can be done here?

I have a wait stage as well
1. Launch website
2. Wait
3. Write stage to username & pwd
4. wait stage
5. click on LOGIN button.

on step#3 I tried before that focus/centre click or double as well before writing the text into the textbox but none worked.

Comment: What is the site? What framework is it based on?

Comment: its nothing fancy about the site its some school site.

Comment: https://ryan.myclassboard.com/RyanDefault.aspx

Comment: The fields themselves may have some `onchange` functionality set on them to only perform the login if they've been changed. You may have to trigger this using Global Send Keys or using the Invoke Javascript Function / Insert Javascript Snippet functionalities of the platform